# Normal link functionality with click handler on container

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a div containing a link, when I click on the container, I have some AJAX functionality, but I also have a link in the div, which I want to function as a normal link and not trigger the click handler.

```
<div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    <a href="/actions/something/">Edit</a>
</div>

$('.box').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
});
```

I attach the handler to all of the other text in the container, but that wouldn't fire the handler if I click on the box background.

Comment: attach another event handler for anchor and use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either detect the clicked element in the `.box` event handler and then run whatever logic is required:

```
$('.box').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'A') {
    $.ajax({
     // ...
    });
  }
});
```

Or alternatively you can place a separate event handler on the `a` element which stops the event propagating to the `.box`:

```
$('.box a').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. `event.StopPropogation` works on the `a`